# Suppose a $\in \mathbb{Z}$. $a^{2}|a$ if and only if $a \in \{-1,0,1\}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic

Suppose a $\in \mathbb{Z}$. Then $a^{2}|a$ if and only if $a \in \{-1,0,1\}$

So, I have started and this is what I have so far:

**Case 1:** If $a^{2}|a$, then $a \in \{-1,0,1\}$. For the sake of contradiction, let's assume that $a\notin \{-1,0,1\}$

... (I am able to solve this case perfectly fine)

**Case 2:** If $a \in \{-1,0,1\}$, then $a^{2}|a$.

This is where I am stuck. I'm not sure which direction to take. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You must have some huge logical misconception, what you can't do is by far the easiest bit. For this reason I'm tagging the question (logic) as well.

Comment: This is the easier part. All you need to show is that $1^2$ divides $1$, that $(-1)^2$ divides $-1$, and that $0$ divides $0^2$.

Comment: @GitGud I think I just over analyzed, to be honest. I proved the first case fine using contradiction and 2 cases for a > 1 and a < -1. But for some reason I couldn't solve this part directly. Thanks!

Comment: @Harry Case 2 is easy because it requires very little work and is straightforward.  To check if for all $a \in \{ -1, 0 , 1 \}$, $a^{2} | a$, all you need to do is square each element of the set, and check that the square divides the original.  There are only three elements, so it should only take you 2 minutes max. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$b|a$ means there is an integer $k$ such that $a=k \cdot b$.

$$-1 = -1 \cdot (-1)^2$$
$$0=0 \cdot 0^2$$
$$1=1 \cdot 1^2$$

Comment: It might also be helpful to mention that $a\in \{-1,0,1\}\iff a=-1\lor a=0\lor a=1$.

Comment: Ah so, I just need to show that a2|a for each a=-1, a=0 and a=1? Easy enough. Thanks