# Proving that $a$ is an element of a set $A$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am supposed to prove that if $a \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $a^2\mid a$, then $a \in \{-1,0,1\}$.

If I let $B = \{-1,0,1\}$ and $\overline{B} = \mathbb{Z} \setminus B$, is it sufficient to show that $a \notin \overline{B}$? $(a \notin \overline{B}$ because if we pick any $a \geq 2$ or any $a \leq -2$, then $a = a^2k$ will not hold for any $k \in \mathbb{Z})$

Or more generally, if we prove that an element is not contained in the set complement, can we conclude that the element must be in the set?

Proof (Contrapositive).

Let $B = \{-1,0,1\}$ and $B^c = \mathbb{Z}\setminus B$. Let $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}$ be the universal set containing $B$ and its complement. Suppose that $a \not\in B$ and $a \in B^c$. If this is the case, then either $a \geq 2$ or $a \leq -2$, but there is no $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ that satisfies $a = a^2k$ for these values of $a$, so $a^2\not\mid a$. Therefore, $a^2\mid a$ only if $a \in B = \{-1,0,1\}. \hspace{1mm} \Box$

Comment: [Related](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/992497/suppose-a-in-mathbbz-a2a-if-and-only-if-a-in-1-0-1/992503#comment2030638_992503).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Or more generally, if we prove that an element is not contained in the set complement, can we conclude that the element must be in the set?

Yes. An element is either in a set or it is not in a set.

(Though, this is a bit imprecise, as pointed out by *Some Math Student* in the below comments:
Technically, when considering the complement of a set, one usually considers the concerned *whole*. Let $A \in \Omega$. If $x \notin A^c$, then $x \in A \iff  x \in \Omega$. That is, if $x$ is not in the *whole* of which we're speaking in the first place, it is both in the complement of $A$ and **not** in $A$.)

Comment: It might be a bit trivial, but for this one could be a bit more accurate in describing what the complement actually is - since the complement is not unique but depending on the whole you're looking at. So if we have a set $A\subset \Omega$, then $x\in A^c \iff (x\notin A \wedge x\in \Omega)$. So we need to have our element existing *somewhere* in the whole set we're looking at. In this particular case, though, this is obviously true.

Comment: @SomeMathStudent Is there usually a distinction made between complement and absolute complement?

Comment: Well, in this case, you usually wouldn't distinguish, I suppose, since it is fairly obvious that you're talking to the complement $A^c=\mathbb{Z}\setminus A$. But, just generally, it is a bit imprecise to say that $a\notin A \Rightarrow a \in A^c$, since in something like the above task, given $A$ are eg odd naturals, we also wouldn't say $\sqrt{2}\in A^c$, even though $\sqrt{2}$ is obviously not an odd natural number.

Comment: How could we make $a \notin A^c \Rightarrow a \in A$ precise?

Comment: In this case  $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}?$

Comment: @SomeMathStudent Ah! I will make the edit. Indeed, in this case $\Omega = \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy I added a proof to the problem. Let me know what you think. Thanks.